# Python The problem is after calculate I can't set up new calculated value for "Label"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wanna do some simple program on Python.
The program calculate your normal weight. You write your age and height.
The problem is after calculate I can't set up new calculated value for "Label"
How can I do that?

**here is program code**

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():                  #button click
    p = int(age.get())          #try ti get value of your age from Entry
    b = int(height.get())       #try to get value of your height from Entry
    mas = int(50 + 0.75*(p - 150) + (b - 20) / 4)     #it is calculation
    lbl3.setvar(mas)                                 # here is a problem (i think)

window = Tk()
window.title('Ваш здоровый вес') 
window.geometry('200x200')

lblage = Label(window, text='Ваш возраст')      # Label for Age
lblage.grid(column=0, row=1)

age = Entry(window, width=5)                    # Entry for Age
age.grid(column=1, row=1)

lblheight = Label(window, text='Ваш рост')       #Label for height
lblheight.grid(column=0, row=2)                  

height = Entry(window, width=5)                 # Entry for height
height.grid(column=1, row=2)

button1 = Button(window, text='Получить значение', fg='green', command=clicked)    #Button 
button1.grid(column=0, row=5)

lbl2 = Label(window, text='Ваш здоровый вес')              
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=6)

lbl3 = Label(window)                            #here have to be our calculation
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=6)

window.mainloop()
```

**the program looks**

[image]

**error is**

```py
 " Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim03\PycharmProjects\practice1\weight.py", line 7, in clicked
    lbl3.setvar(mas)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 709, in setvar
    self.tk.setvar(name, value)
TypeError: must be str, bytes or Tcl_Obj, not int"
```

I think the problem is here:

```
def clicked():
    p = int(age.get())
    b = int(height.get())
    mas = int(50 + 0.75*(p - 150) + (b - 20) / 4)
    lbl3.setvar(mas)
```

Comment: Judging by the exception, the .setvar is expecting a string, not an integer, which sort of makes sense since you appear to be updating a label.  `lbl3.setvar(str(mas))` maybe?

Comment: `setvar` isn't the usual way of setting label text as far as I know. I believe `lbl3.config(text=str(mas))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

```
Use the config() method to update multiple attrs subsequent to object creation
fred.config(fg="red", bg="blue")
```

change it on

```
lbl3.config(text=str(mas))
```

Also it looks like you should replace Возраст and Рост - it will calculate healthy weight correctly, but now does not

Answer (score 0):

ok so this is a very simple problem to solve. Where you have converted entry values to int for calculation, the return value was also an int value. Label text can't be int. Just follow this code in your clicked function:

```
def clicked():
    p = int(age.get())
    b = int(height.get())
    mas = int(50 + 0.75*(p - 150) + (b - 20) / 4)
    lbl3.setvar(str(mas))
```

The str() made the mas a string from input.

Thank You!

Comment: thank you. It's helped to solve error, but  didnt replace value, I mean just nothing happening.   Perhaps problem is              
 lbl3 = Label(window)        
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=6)

Comment: Hi, actually I think the error is that I made a typo. I forgot to put the end bracket. Please copy the code again and run it.